# how to convert date month from int to varchar?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, date

i would like to ask how convert integer to month name in sql server 2005. Example My field is 01-12 , i would like to display as January - December .

anyone can help me?

Comment: which programming language is it?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MonthName =
  CASE month
     WHEN 1 THEN 'January'
     WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
     WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
     WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
     WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
     WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
     WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
     WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
     WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
     WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
     WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
     WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
     ELSE 'What kind of calendar is it?'
  END
```

## See also:

- [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Thanks...it is a good method but isit got other method, i prefer want dynamic code

Answer (score 1):

In C# we can use 
For Full name of Month like january-December

> Date.ToString("MMMM")

for jan-dec u can use

> Date.ToString("MMM")

Answer (score 1):

TO use in Stored Procedure of Sql u can use this

> SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, @mydate-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS
>   datetime)))

where @mydate can be 1,2,3...

Comment: can i ask,why need put CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime), and why@mydate need -1?

Comment: Cast will cast '2008-01-01' to date time  and @mydate -1 will decrement it the simple logic i have used :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this way, you create one sclar function..

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertMonthName
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @m      nvarchar(2)
)
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @result varchar(20)

    DECLARE @MNO INT
    SET @MNO = CAST(@M AS INT)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    if(@m = 1)
        SET @result = 'JANUARY'
    else if(@m = 2)
        SET @result = 'FEBRUARY'
    else if(@m = 3)
        SET @result = 'MARCH'
    else if(@m = 4)
        SET @result = 'APRIL'
    else if(@m = 5)
        SET @result = 'MAY'
    else if(@m = 6)
        SET @result = 'JUNE'
    else if(@m = 7)
        SET @result = 'JULY'
    else if(@m = 8)
        SET @result = 'AUGUST'
    else if(@m = 9)
        SET @result = 'SEPTEMBER'
    else if(@m = 10)
        SET @result = 'OCTOBER'
    else if(@m = 11)
        SET @result = 'NOVEMBER'
    else if(@m = 12)
        SET @result = 'DECEMBER'



    RETURN @result

END
```

-- from your sql script

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(5)
SET @VAR = '01-12'

SELECT dbo.ConvertMonthName(LEFT(@VAR,2)) + ' - ' + dbo.ConvertMonthName(RIGHT(@VAR,2)) [colname]
```

Comment: thanks, good way also,but this seem like more hard code. Do u know another method. Anyway,thanks your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you don't like about the other answers (what does "I prefer dynamic code" mean?) but since you are using a database, the simplest solution is to store the names in a table. Then you can easily add more columns in future if you want to support month names in multiple languages, for example.

If you do a lot of work with dates the best solution of all is to create a full [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459260/calendar-table-week-number-of-month) (you can find plenty of discussions about them on this site) because then you can store as many names or other attributes as you like for a specific date without using any code at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[MonthName] (@monthNum int)
    RETURNS varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE WHEN @monthNum BETWEEN 1 AND 12
            THEN DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, @monthNum, '2000-12-01'))
            ELSE NULL
        END
END
```