# For Mondays I need to set default date to previous Friday for App?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When a Report is run on a Monday it needs to set the default date to Friday ? Also 4 other conditions looking at the requirments. How to do this in an sql statement is the question.

So in pseudo code,

If today's date is Monday then set default date to Friday with full date format.

If today's date is Saturday then set default date to Friday with full date format.

If today's date is Sunday then set default date to Friday with full date format.

If any other day , then set default date to previous working day .

So need one sql statement maybe with a case statement .

Now I found these statements which give day of week so now need to do next part which may be a case statement or maybe a function ? This is the part I need assistance pl.

```
select datename(dw,getdate()) --Monday
select datepart(dw,getdate()) -- 1
```

Comment: What is default date? A column in a table?

Comment: Sorry deafult date is just a date value that will be passed to an application.

Comment: Sql Server 2008 is the version .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Previous business day in a week with that of current Business Day using sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922756/how-to-get-previous-business-day-in-a-week-with-that-of-current-business-day-usi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

DECLARE @day DATE = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT @day = DATEADD
(
  DAY, 
  CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @day) IN (1,2) 
      THEN  -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @day)+1) 
    ELSE -1 
  END, 
  @day);

SELECT @day;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if the WEEKDAY (or dw) value is 3-6 (Tuesday through Saturday), then subtract one day.  Otherwise subtract an additional day for Sunday and an addition two days for Monday.

Fortunately, the value for Sunday is 1 and the value for Monday is 2, so you can just subtract those values for those days.

```
DECLARE @DefaultDate datetime
SET @DefaultDate = 
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) IN (1,2) -- OR (1,7) outside the U.S.
            THEN DATEADD(DAY, (-1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())), GETDATE())                       
        ELSE
            DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
    END
```

Comment: *‘Fortunately, the value for Sunday is 1 and the value for Monday is 2’* – well, I'm happy for you then! :) But not everyone lives in USA or wherever else Sunday is the first day of the week. And indeed, the code samples in the question seem to suggest that the OP's week starts on Monday.

Comment: @AndriyM LOL.  Thanks for mentioning that!