# How can I set last business date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am a new learner in SQL. I need to declare the last business date in my query. For instance,

- if current day is Monday, then return last Friday.
- if current day is from Tuesday to Friday, then return yesterday.

The weekends and national holiday have to be excluded.

I need this sort of format:

```
declare @LastBizDate as datetime
set @LastBizDate = (DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                      WHEN 'Saturday' THEN -1 
                      WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                      ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())))
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Previous business day in a week with that of current Business Day using sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922756/how-to-get-previous-business-day-in-a-week-with-that-of-current-business-day-usi)

Comment: If you need to account for public holidays, invest in a Calendar Table; SQL Server has no idea what public holidays you observe.

Comment: If you are interested in **dates**, why are you using datetime datatype?

Comment: Hi thanks I know where the problem is in my code. I should use 'Sunday' and 'Monday' instead of 'Saturday' and 'Sunday'. Larnu's link is helpful!

Comment: That still doesn't account for holidays.

Comment: It also doesn't account for 'observed' holidays - where the holiday is observed on Friday when it falls on Saturday - or observed on Monday when it falls on Sunday.  Nor does it account for other holidays.  This is why you need - at a minimum - a holiday table that lists each holiday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @LastBizDate as datetime
set @LastBizDate = CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
                      WHEN 'Monday' THEN GETDATE()-3
                      WHEN 'Sunday' THEN GETDATE()-2
                      ELSE GETDATE()-1 END
PRINT @LastBizDate
```

Comment: I just noticed it. I should use 'Sunday' and 'Monday' instead of 'Saturday' and 'Sunday'. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `NationalHolidayIndicator` or `NationalHoliday` are already in your date table, use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT d.[Date]
, d.NationalHolidayIndicator
--, d.NationalHoliday
, (SELECT MAX([Date])
   FROM [Date] 
   WHERE [Date] < d.[Date]
     AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d.[Date]) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
     AND d.NationalHolidayIndicator = 'no'
     --AND d.NationalHoliday IS NULL
  ) as PreviousBusinessDay


FROM [Date] d
```

If you don't already have `NationalHolidayIndicator` and `NationalHoliday`, For the U.S. that might look something like this:

```
case 
  when datepart(month, dt) = 1 and datepart(day, dt) = 1 and datepart(weekday, dt) between 2 and 6 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 1 and datepart(day, dt) = 2 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 12 and datepart(day, dt) = 31 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 6 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 1 and datepart(day, dt) between 15 and 21 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 and datepart(year, dt) > 1985 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 2 and datepart(day, dt) between 15 and 21 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 5 and datepart(day, dt) > 24 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 7 and datepart(day, dt) = 4 and datepart(weekday, dt) between 2 and 6 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 7 and datepart(day, dt) = 5 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 7 and datepart(day, dt) = 3 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 6 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 9 and datepart(day, dt) between 1 and 7 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 10 and datepart(day, dt) between 8 and 14 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dt) = 11 and datepart(weekday, dt) between 2 and 6 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dt) = 12 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dt) = 10 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 6 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dt) between 22 and 28 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 5 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 12 and datepart(day, dt) = 25 and datepart(weekday, dt) between 2 and 6 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 12 and datepart(day, dt) = 26 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'yes'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 12 and datepart(day, dt) = 24 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 6 then 'yes'
  else 'no'
end as NationalHolidayIndicator
, case
  when datepart(month, dt) = 1 and datepart(day, dt) = 1 then 'New Year''s Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 1 and datepart(day, dt) = 2 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'New Year''s Day - legal'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 12 and datepart(day, dt) = 31 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 6 then 'New Year''s Day - legal'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 1 and datepart(day, dt) between 15 and 21 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 and datepart(year, dt) > 1985 then 'Martin Luther King Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 2 and datepart(day, dt) between 15 and 21 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'Presidents'' Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 5 and datepart(day, dt) > 24 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'Memorial Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 7 and datepart(day, dt) = 4 then 'Independence Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 7 and datepart(day, dt) = 5 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'Independence Day - legal'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 7 and datepart(day, dt) = 3 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 6 then 'Independence Day - legal'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 9 and datepart(day, dt) between 1 and 7 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'Labor Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 10 and datepart(day, dt) between 8 and 14 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'Columbus Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dt) = 11 then 'Veterans Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dt) = 12 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'Veterans Day - legal'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dt) = 10 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 6 then 'Veterans Day - legal'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dt) between 22 and 28 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 5 then 'Thanksgiving Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dateadd(day, -1, dt)) between 22 and 28 and datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, -1, dt)) = 5 and datepart(year, dt) between 1977 and 2013 then 'Thanksgiving, Day After'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 11 and datepart(day, dateadd(day, -1, dt)) between 22 and 28 and datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, -1, dt)) = 5 and datepart(year, dt) > 2014 then 'Native American Heritage Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 12 and datepart(day, dt) = 25 then 'Christmas Day'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 12 and datepart(day, dt) = 26 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 2 then 'Christmas Day - legal'
  when datepart(month, dt) = 12 and datepart(day, dt) = 24 and datepart(weekday, dt) = 6 then 'Christmas Day - legal'
end as NationalHoliday
```

...although my holiday names and dates are from my State laws, not Federal laws.