# Getting “before two days” date sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012, dateadd

I want to get two days before from current date and that date should not be Saturday and Sunday today is 1st July 2021 so i need to get data for 30th jun 2021 and 29th jun 2021 and that day should not be Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Previous business day in a week with that of current Business Day using sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922756/how-to-get-previous-business-day-in-a-week-with-that-of-current-business-day-usi) (the logic is *identical* apart from you are subtracting 2 days from the current date first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT CASE DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())
       WHEN 2 THEN DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE())  -- Monday becomes Friday
       WHEN 3 THEN DATEADD(day, -4, GETDATE())  -- Tuesday becomes Friday
       ELSE DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE())         -- otherwise roll back 2 days
       END;
```

The above answer assumes that server settings place Sunday as day 1, Monday as day 2, ..., and Saturday as day 7.  Without this assumption my answer might be *worthless*.

Comment: Worth nothing this *assumes* the user's `@@DATEFIRST` setting. As an Englishman, for example, this incorrectly returns `2021-06-26` if the date were `2021-06-29`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26e0ab7b0986404a16020bc5c7cdb53f)