# How to get the week start and end dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have variable called `WeekBeginDate` and I want only to pull data for that week. For example, if the beginning of the week date is  `07/21/2014` which is `Monday` in this case, then I want only to pull the data from `07/21/2014`   to  `7/27/2014`.

The variable will always contain  the date for the beginning of the week only but I don’t have the date for the end of the week.

The week begins on `Monday` and ends on `Sunday`. I can’t figure out how to calculate or sum the number of hours if I only have the date for the beginning of week.

```
SELECT DT, sum (TOT_HOURS)as TOT_HOURS FROM MYTABLE where DT >= @WeekBeginDate and <=@WeekEndDate group by DT
```

Note, that I only have the variable for the `WeekBeginDate`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the Starting and ending date of week? In Sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007861/getting-the-starting-and-ending-date-of-week-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

just modify your table columns in this CTE it may works :

```
;WITH workhours AS
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY
                ,   -(DATEPART(dw, DT) -1)
                ,   DT) AS week_start
        ,   DATEADD(DAY
                ,   7 - (DATEPART(dw, DT))
                ,   DT) AS week_end

    FROM    MYTABLE
)
SELECT      week_start
        ,   week_end
        ,   SUM(TOT_HOURS) total_hrs_per_week
FROM        workhours
GROUP BY    week_start
        ,   week_end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add 6 days to the beginning of the week 
and group by something else if you need total weekly hours, i'm calling it "id". 
not by dt (or don't group at all if it is a total for the whole table):

```
SELECT id, DT, sum (TOT_HOURS)as TOT_HOURS FROM MYTABLE 
where DT BETWEEN @WeekBeginDate and DATEADD(d,6,@WeekBeginDate)
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be of some use to you. I am casting to date so the 24 hrs of day is considered.

```
DECLARE @WeekBeginDate DATETIME

SET @WeekBeginDate = '2014-07-28 12:08:31.633';
WITH MYTABLE (DT,TOT_HOURS)
    AS (
    SELECT '2014-06-27 00:08:31.633',5 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014-07-27 00:08:31.633',5 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014-07-28 00:08:31.633',1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014-07-29 00:08:31.633',1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014-07-30 00:08:31.633',1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014-07-31 00:08:31.633',1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014-08-01 00:08:31.633',1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014-08-02 00:08:31.633',1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014-08-03 00:08:31.633',1
    )
SELECT  CAST(@WeekBeginDate AS DATE) AS StartDate,
       DATEADD(d, 6, CAST(@WeekBeginDate AS DATE)) AS EndDate,
       SUM (TOT_HOURS)AS TOT_HOURS
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE CAST(DT AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@WeekBeginDate AS DATE) AND DATEADD(d, 6, CAST(@WeekBeginDate AS DATE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 6 (or 7) days...

```
SELECT DT, sum (TOT_HOURS)as TOT_HOURS FROM MYTABLE 
where DT BETWEEN @WeekBeginDate and @WeekBeginDate + 6 group by DT
```

Answer (score 0):

select @weekBeginDate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)

select @WeekEndDate = DATEADD(dd, 6, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))

SELECT DT, sum (TOT_HOURS)as TOT_HOURS FROM MYTABLE where DT >= @WeekBeginDate and <=@WeekEndDate group by DT

Answer (score 0):

Here is where having a calendar table would be very useful,
especially if your logic needs to change if Monday is a holiday.

Basically create a table with pre-calculated values for weeks and just join to it.

http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one