# SQL Statement with the actual week

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table which look like this:

```
  Date       |    Day     |    Ingredients
-------------------------------------------
2014-08-20   | Wednesday  | Salt
2014-08-21   | Thursday   | Sugar
2014-08-22   | Friday     | Salt&Sugar
2014-08-28   | Thursday   | Salt
```

And I want to have only the dates there are in one week. Should I make an extra column 'Week' with the number of the week or is there a solution where I can set the beginning and the end of a week to only have the actual week. So I have all rows from the actual week.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE *`Date is in the actual week`*
```

Comment: How do you specify which week?

Comment: why don't you use 7 queries?(1 per day)

Comment: A week goes from Monday to Sunday for me, and even it is Sunday I need the data from the past 6 days. And when its Monday after that I need the data from Monday and the next 6 days.

Comment: This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126/how-do-you-get-the-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-week-number-in-sql

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007861/getting-the-starting-and-ending-date-of-week-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean to get the data of current week?

Use the **[YEARWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)** function.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE, 1)
```

*Update:*
Use **[mode 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)** if the beginning of week is Monday.

Comment: You'll most likely want to add [mode 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) to YEARWEEK.