# How to get week start date & week end date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I want to calculate weeks of a month starting from 1st of every month and not from Monday.
It needs to be 1st. to 7th., 8th. to 14th., 15th. to 21st., 22nd. to 28th., and 29th. till month-end.

So If I pass date as **2015-12-30 00:00**, then it should return week start date as **2015-12-29 00:00** And Week End Date as **2016-01-01 00:00**

I tried following script, but it is giving me Week start as Monday.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the Starting and ending date of week? In Sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007861/getting-the-starting-and-ending-date-of-week-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to establish the current week of the month, given by the current day of the month divided by 7 (rounded up), Then you can get the day of the start of the current week by multiplying the week number by 7 and adding a day. Finally you can get the date of the week start using the first of the current month and `DATEADD(DAY`. The stages are:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2015-12-30';

SELECT  WeekNumberOfMonth = CEILING(DATEPART(DAY, @Date) / 7.0),
        WeekStartDay =  1 + FLOOR((DATEPART(DAY, @Date) - 1) / 7.0) * 7,
        FirstDayOfMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date), 0),
        WeekStart = DATEADD(DAY, 
                            (CEILING(DATEPART(DAY, @Date) / 7.0) - 1) * 7,
                            DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date), 0));
```

Which gives:

```
WeekNumberOfMonth   WeekStartDay    FirstDayOfMonth     WeekStart
--------------------------------------------------------------------
5                   29              2015-12-01          2015-12-29
```

Finally, the weekend requires a case statement to check if it is still in the same month as the week start:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2015-12-30';

SELECT  d.WeekStart,
        Weekend = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 7, WeekStart) > StartOfNextMonth
                            THEN StartOfNextMonth
                        ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 7, WeekStart)
                    END
FROM    (   SELECT  WeekStart = DATEADD(DAY, 
                                        ((DATEPART(DAY, @Date) - 1) / 7.0) * 7, 
                                        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date), 0)),
                    StartOfNextMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date) + 1, 0)
        ) AS d;
```

Which gives:

```
WeekStart       Weekend
----------------------------
2015-12-29      2016-01-01
```

**Further Testing**

```
SELECT  d.[Date],
        d.WeekStart,
        Weekend = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 7, WeekStart) > StartOfNextMonth
                            THEN StartOfNextMonth
                        ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 7, WeekStart)
                    END
FROM    (   SELECT  dt.[Date],
                    WeekStart = DATEADD(DAY, 
                                        (CEILING(DATEPART(DAY, dt.[Date]) / 7.0) - 1) * 7, 
                                        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt.[Date]), 0)),
                    StartOfNextMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt.[Date]) + 1, 0)
            FROM    (VALUES 
                        (CONVERT(DATE, '20151106')),
                        (CONVERT(DATE, '20151107')),
                        (CONVERT(DATE, '20151220')),
                        (CONVERT(DATE, '20151228')),
                        (CONVERT(DATE, '20151230')),
                        (CONVERT(DATE, '20160104'))
                    ) dt ([Date])
        ) AS d;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Date            WeekStart       Weekend
-------------------------------------------
2015-11-06      2015-11-01      2015-11-08
2015-11-07      2015-11-01      2015-11-08
2015-12-20      2015-12-15      2015-12-22
2015-12-28      2015-12-22      2015-12-29
2015-12-30      2015-12-29      2016-01-01
2016-01-04      2016-01-01      2016-01-08
```

Comment: Hi @GarethD when i pass Date as '2015-12-20 00:00' it returns  WeekStart : 2015-12-15 00:00:00.000 and WeekEnd 2015-12-21 00:00:00.000 . Ideally WeekEnd Should be 2015-12-22 00:00:00.000

Comment: One more doubt, when I pass Date as '2015-11-07 19:07:09.880' it return WeekStart : 2015-11-08 00:00:00.000 and WeekEnd 2015-11-15 00:00:00.000 . Where as it should have returned WeekStart : 2015-11-01 00:00:00.000 and WeekEnd 2015-11-08 00:00:00.000

Comment: Yep, sorry, needed to deduct a day when calculating the week number, since it requires a 0 based system but week days are based 1. Should be OK now.

Comment: Still not proper. Now this is returning WeekStart : 2015-11-06 00:00:00.000 Weekend : 2015-11-13 00:00:00.000

Comment: Again, apologies, and also apologies for the delay in editing, I have now corrected the issues (I think) and added a further query to allow testing multiple dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEADD() on EOMONTH(). E.g. Minus one day from EOMONTH to get how many days in the month.

To calculate our how many weeks in a month, take the EOMONTH and divide this by 7. Removing the remainder by using the FLOOR() function.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT EOMONTH ( @date ) AS 'This Month';
SELECT EOMONTH ( @date, 1 ) AS 'Next Month';
SELECT EOMONTH ( @date, -1 ) AS 'Last Month';
GO
```

Comment: The OP cannot use EOMONTH as it is only available in SQL Server 2012 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late, but here's what I use:

```
DECLARE @now datetime = GETDATE();

-- strip the time part from your date
DECLARE @date datetime = CONVERT(date, @now);

-- do the day of week math
DECLARE @start datetime = DATEADD(d, 1 - DATEPART(w, @date), @date),
        @end   datetime = DATEADD(d, 8 - DATEPART(w, @date), @date);

SELECT @start AS [WeekStart], @now AS [Now], @end AS [WeekEnd];
```

[image: SQL Week start and end from date]

Just remember that the `BETWEEN` operator makes an inclusive `[@start, @end]` date range, so technically you should use `@start <= [Date] AND [Date] < @end` or subtract 1 millisecond from `@end`--unless you can live with the 1/86,400,000 chance of an event being recorded at exactly 0 milliseconds of the next week!