# Bigquery: Getting first day of the week/month in standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

In Bigquery's **legacy** SQL, I can get the start of week for a date by using

```
SELECT DATE((UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP('2017-04-13 20:58:06 UTC')), 0)))
```

which returns `2017-04-09`.

Is there a way to do this in BigQuery's **standard** SQL? There doesn't seem to be any equivalents for `UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK` and `UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH`.

Comment: Although there is a SQL Standard, SQL DB vendors generally have variations in how they handle dates.  What specific SQL platform are you looking for?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007861/getting-the-starting-and-ending-date-of-week-in-sql-server

Comment: @WesH I'm using Google's Bigquery. I'm not sure which exact flavour of SQL they're using

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like BigQuery has a function named [TIMESTAMP_TRUNC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_trunc) which may do what you want.  It is referenced as the replacement for UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(t) in LegacySQL when used with a Day datepart.  It also accepts Week and Month as a parameter which may meet your requirements.

```
TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '2008-12-25 15:30:00', WEEK, 'UTC')
```

Here is the page for [migrating from Legacy to Standard sql](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Comment: Good find! Works like a charm. That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

This is better option that works now:

```
select DATE_TRUNC(date( '2008-12-25 15:30:00'), month)
```

Comment: Old topic but it still shows up high in search results. We can now use `LAST_DAY(date)` for last day of the month