# Find the Date range of week by current date in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to find record by this week just declare current date. 
Example:

```
     select datename(dw,getdate())  -- Example today is Friday "27-04-2012"
```

so how can i get date range

```
     start on monday "23-04-2012" or sunday "22-04-2012"  As @dateStart to

     end on sunday "29-04-2012"  or saturday "28-04-2012" As @dateEnd
```

then i can select query by

```
     select * from table where date>=@dateStart  AND date<=@dateEnd
```

Comment: You need to test for which day of the week you're on and subtract/add the relevant number of days to your date.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are some helpful commands to get each day of the week

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -2) SatOfPreviousWeek,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -1) SunOfCurrentWeek,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) MondayOfCurrentWeek,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 1) TuesOfCurrentWeek,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 2) WedOfCurrentWeek,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 3) ThursOfCurrentWeek,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 4) FriOfCurrentWeek,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 5) SatOfCurrentWeek
```

you would then use these in your query to get the date range:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourDate >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -1) -- Sunday
AND yourDate <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 5) -- Saturday
```

Answer (score 5):

So you want only records from this week?

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table t 
WHERE t.date >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0)
AND   t.date <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The queries that others have suggested may work, but you haven't defined what a "week" is for you. Depending on the country/region and the business reasons, a week could be Sun-Sat, Mon-Sun, Mon-Fri etc.

Therefore the best solution for finding the first and last days of the week is probably a [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459260/calendar-table-week-number-of-month) where you pre-populate the first and last days of the week for every date that you'll need. Then you can use a simple query to get the correct start and end dates to use in your query:

```
select @StartDate = FirstDayOfWeek, @EndDate = LastDayOfWeek
from dbo.Calendar
where BaseDate = @SomeDate
```

This solution also has the advantage that you can easily work with different definitions of a week by adding new columns to your calendar table.